# Run Asp.Net core on Visual Studio as 32bit

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I just converted a project from MVC 4 to ASP.NET Core 1.0. This project does some pinvoke on a 32bit dll and when I try to debug it, I get that bad image exception.

If I deploy it using `dotnet publish -c Release -r win7-x86` it works perfectly fine, but I can't debug it or run through visual studio.

Comment: Make sure Visual Studio is set to run/debug as x86.  Sounds like you might be running on 64 bit machine with [Any CPU]?

Comment: still doesn't work... I change to x86 but still doesn't work. IntPtr.Size still returns 8

Comment: have you added "platform" : "x86" in "buildOptions" section in project.json?

Comment: as a last resort you can start your app from command line and attach the VS debugger to the process (ctrl+alt+p)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to either publish the app as standalone app 32bit or, if it's a shared framework app, then you need to start it with a 32 bit dotnet.

If you already have the app running in 32 bit mode, then you can attach VS to it.

If you want VS to always use the 32 bit dotnet then you have to uninstall the dotnet in program files (or just remove it from the system PATH) and then install a dotnet that's 32 bit, making sure it's on the PATH. It's important to note that system PATH takes priority in Windows so adding something to the user's PATH will not work unless you remove the old one.

PS: I assume you're running on a 64 bit OS. Otherwise, you get the 32 bit dotnet by default.

Comment: worked! I'm pretty sure that there will be an easier way soon, like just change to x86 when debugging.